# Where did "Nemo Nobody" get his name?

Tags: analysis, mr-nobody

In the movie [Mr.Nobody](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0485947/) the character played by [Jared Leto](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001467/?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm) is called "Nemo Nobody" as in the First Name Last Name syntax. This we see when Nemo kisses Elise in the car just before the explosion, smiles and days "Mrs. Nobody"

My Question: ***How did he(Jared Leto's character) come to own this name?***

1. Did he give it to himself?
2. My guess is: in the movie at 18:49 during kid Nemo's monologue of "Do I exist" we see his mother reciting this poem "**Eenie meenie minie mo**". Does the kid Nemo take this verse to be "**My Nemo**" instead of "**minie mo**" and thus assume that must be his name? And may be later on, on learning Nemo means Nobody, takes his name as this?

I could not find any reference to this verse in the context of Nemo's naming anywhere. Any help would be great.

Comment: “nemo” means “nobody” in Latin

Comment: According to https://film.avclub.com/mr-nobody-1798178513 : "The character’s name alludes to both Jules Verne and The Odyssey, but Mr. Nobody’s expansive literary ambitions turn out to have a powerful ordering principle: sentimentality."

Comment: @BCdotWEB Thanks a lot but I was aware of the etymology of the word "Nemo". My question was how Nemo got his name? Did he give it to himself or someone named him that way in the story?